# Is there a way to get back the commits in this case?

Tags: git, push

I created a git bare repo today, and added some dotfiles and configs. The thing that mattered the most was my qtile config, since I worked a lot on it.

After adding everything, I pushed and all was good.

I did this because I was planning to distro hop, and I whipped my disk clean after that (all other important files are saved on the cloud).

Installed new distro (EndeavourOS, before I was using Manjaro) and created a new git bare repo.

This is were things went wrong. It did not allowed me to pull files after adding the remote repo, so I figured, let me just add and push everything I have in this PC (which is not much since it is a fresh install) now and even if it overwrites something, I'll just check git and copy the differences.

Well, I forced pushed the things I added and because I hadn't made a pull before, that commit overwrote the previous commit that I did before in which I added all the configs important to me.

I went to the repo in github and all files are lost, and there is only one commit showing (the one I force pushed).

I know I did several things wrong to put myself in this situation, but I wanted to know if there is any way to recover those files that I previously had in my repo and were overwritten.

Comment: you used `git reset --hard`  and `git push --force` ?

Comment: You can use `git reflog` to see old commits before a hard reset.

Comment: I used git push --force but I did not have any local commits before that, so now in my remote repo I only have one commit.
Thats why git reflog doesnt work, because I have no commits before.

Answer (score 2):

GitHub has an [events API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/activity/events#list-repository-events).

Look for `PushEvent`s, and the `"before"` field in the payload for such events.

Once you get the commits hash, you should be able to run `git fetch origin <sha>`, then `git checkout <sha>:README.md`.

*note:* the `<sha>` in `git fetch origin <sha>` should be the complete 40 characters sha1, not a short sha -- github will treat anything that isn't a 40 characters long hexadecimal string as a reference name.

Comment: Thank you very much @LeGEC, you saved me.
This worked exactly as intended.
I cannot express how thankful I am, I was dreading having to spend days configuring everything again.
Thanks again!

Comment: I think the merit should go to the GitHub team, and the git developers :D:D:D glad this answer helped